# How can I test multi-touch on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, multi-touch

I don't have an Android phone now, but I really want to test Multi-touch or Shake feauture. How can I do this on Emulator?

Answer (score 6):

[Multitouch in the emulator is still not supported.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/472b35294374a032)